# Show that $\|M|ψ⟩\|^2 =⟨ψ|M^† M|ψ⟩$

Tags: quantum-state, textbook-and-exercises

I'm a newcomer to Quantum Computing and I'm currently working through a tutorial shown [here](https://quantum.country/).

At one point (second last section in Part II), there is an exercise that I'm really struggling with. I'm new to bra-ket notation and, while I can spot some identities given previously in the tutorial that might be useful for the exercise, I'm not able to make much headway.

The question is:
Show that for any matrix $M$ and vector $|ψ⟩$, the following identity holds, expressing the length of $M|\psi⟩$:

$\|M|\psi\rangle\|^2 = \langle\psi|M^\dagger M |\psi\rangle.$

My rather poor attempt starts with recognising that $M^\dagger M = MM=M^2=I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix, substituting this into the original formula. This identity was given earlier in the tutorial. This gives me:

$\|M|\psi\rangle\|^2 = M^2\langle\psi|\psi\rangle.$ (1)

Then, noting another identity provided, that $\langle\psi|\psi\rangle = |||\psi\rangle||^2$ and substituting into (1) gives:

$\|M|\psi\rangle\|^2 = M^2|||\psi\rangle||^2$ (2)

At this point I'm basically stuck, I can't tell if I've provided proof, if I'm on the right track but not quite there, or if I'm totally wrong!

The only other thought I'd had is to use the identity:

$\langle\psi|M^\dagger = (M|\psi\rangle)^\dagger$,

but in honesty didn't really get any further than thinking I might need to use it.

I've been able to more or less follow the examples that the tutorial has worked through, but for this exercise I'm struggling even to understand how to proceed. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: The identity $M^\dagger M=M^2=I$ does not generally hold unless you assume that $M$ is a self-adjoint unitary.

Comment: Why is $M^\dagger M = I$? The question said for any matrix $M$ not necessary unitary matrix $M$

Comment: Thankyou both for your replies. At least I know now that I'm on the wrong path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows from the definition of the [norm on an inner-product spac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Norm_properties)e (that is a vector space equipped with an inner-product). For any vector $|\psi\rangle$ in an $n$-dimensional inner-product space $V$ we have by definition that $$\||\psi\rangle\|^2=\bigg\langle |\psi\rangle\bigg||\psi\rangle\bigg\rangle=\langle \psi|\psi\rangle.$$

If $M$ is any matrix $n\times n$ (i.e. a linear operator acting on $V$, written $M: V\rightarrow V$) then we have $$M|\psi\rangle=|\phi\rangle$$ for some $|\phi\rangle\in V$. The norm of $M|\psi\rangle=|\phi\rangle$ is then $$\|M|\psi\rangle\|^2=\||\phi\rangle\|^2=\langle \phi|\phi\rangle=\langle M\psi|M\psi\rangle.$$

Finally, for any linear operator $M$ acting on an inner-product space we define the [*adjoint*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint) as the operator $M^\dagger$ which satisfies the equation $$\langle Mv|w\rangle=\langle v|M^\dagger |w\rangle,$$ for all $|v\rangle,|w\rangle\in V$.

Thus, using our definition of the adjoint we see that $$\|M|\psi\rangle\|^2=\langle M\psi|M\psi\rangle=\langle\psi|M^\dagger M|\psi\rangle,$$ as desired.

I would also recommend reviewing the [Bra-ket Wikepdia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation), especially the section on [common pitfalls with the notation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation#Pitfalls_and_ambiguous_uses)

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I must admit, a lot of that is going over my head right now but I will try to understand it.

Comment: The part of the answer I'm trying to get to grips with is the adjoint. 

*...we define the adjoint as the operator M† which satisfies the equation*

$⟨Mv|w⟩=⟨v|M^†w⟩,$ (1)

for all $v,w∈V.$

*Thus, using our definition of the adjoint we see that*
$∥M|ψ⟩∥^2=⟨Mψ|Mψ⟩=⟨ψ|M^†M|ψ⟩$ (2)

Now, I'm trying to get from point (1) to point (2). This is my best attempt:

Let *v=$\psi$* and *w=$M\psi$* and substituting into (1).

Thus:$⟨Mv|w⟩=⟨M\psi|M\psi⟩=⟨v|M^†w⟩=⟨\psi|M^†M\psi⟩$

*Almost* looks right, but I can't understand why I have $M\psi⟩$ and not $M|\psi⟩$ at the very end.

Comment: It is just a clash of the bra-ket notation with conventional mathematical notation, one usually accepts that $|M\psi \rangle=M|\psi\rangle$.

Comment: Using Bra-ket notation you could equivalently use the definition of the adjoint as $\langle M\psi|=\langle \psi|M^\dagger$. Perhaps that's simpler.

Comment: Thank you @Condo, that has been very helpful

Comment: Hello again @Condo, sorry to bring this up again, but I'm still unfortunately struggling to understand bra-ket conventions. You say that |Mψ⟩=M|ψ>, but naively I don't "see" a |Mψ⟩ term in my working. I see |M†Mψ⟩. I sort of understand there is an omitted vertical bar somewhere, but I don't see why that would yield ⟨ψ|M†M|ψ⟩ and not ⟨ψ||M†Mψ⟩.

This notation feels very unintuitive to me, and so far I've yet to have a Eureka moment where I understand why we're even bothering with it!

Comment: $\langle \psi|M^\dagger M|\psi\rangle$ and $\langle \psi||M^\dagger M\psi\rangle$ are exactly the same. To be honest, I think that trying to learn linear algebra with braket notation only makes it more complicated, braket notation only becomes convenient once you understand the mathematics. Perhaps try to learn using standard mathematical notation for vectors and inner products.